# Do we have canonical questions for slow cooking conversions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I am reasonably sure that I recently saw a question asking how to convert a slow cooker recipe for X pounds of meat into a recipe for 2X (or maybe 1/2 X) pounds of meat. I was quite sure that we have, from the early days of the site, a question for each of the scaling directions. After a long search, I gave up and did not close. The question didn't get much attention.

Today, I saw again a similar scaling question: [Cooking a large pork roast in a slow cooker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/52083/how-can-i-cook-a-9-pound-pork-roast-in-a-slow-cooker) Now I thought that, even if I can't find the old questions I'm thinking of, there's 50% chance of it being a dupe of the recent question. So I searched again. And again, I found nothing. Not an old question, but no recent one either.

Can anybody please help out? It seems that my own search fu, or memory, or both, are failing. How many questions do we have on this topic? Can we close some as a duplicate?

Comment: There seem to be quite a few about increasing the cooking *time* for slow-cooker recipes, some of which have been closed as duplicates. There are a handful asking about using a larger cooker than identified in the recipe (without changing the recipe quantities) but the closest I can find to what you describe is actually the opposite case of scaling *down* a recipe: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24172/converting-to-a-2-quart-slow-cooker

Comment: I, too, remember a recent question very similar in nature. When I first saw your comment I started searching for it and it is nowhere to be found. Is it possible that it was deleted?